# Badges not showing in the activity tab of the network profile

Tags: bug, badges, stackexchange.com, network-profile

For example, [my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1529456/user67275?tab=activity):

[image: screenshot showing there are no badges]

In the Badge sub-tab of the Activity tab in my profile, it says 'no activity found' as of 04:30 GMT, April 19, 2023. It is quite weird because I was awarded at least one badge within recent 6 days, and at least two badges within recent 12 days. Other sub-tabs such as posts or comments show my recent activity correctly. What went wrong here or what am I misunderstanding?

(I can see my total number of badges in the flair tab, so I cannot figure out easily which badge I received and when it was)

Comment: Not only you, but it seems everyone. Link for checking this for [current user.](https://stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=activity)

Comment: You omitted the most critical details: this is relevant on the network profile only. This works fine on all sites, on the site itself.

Comment: I found the issue in the query, and have requested a fix from the appropriate team. I'll explain in the dupe target.